# Python subprocess: get all stdout data after proccess has terminated

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I am using subprocess in python to invoke another executable, write some data to it's stdin (close the stream once everything is written - which is how the sub process knows it's recieved everything) and then receive all of it's stdout data after it's terminated - which it will after some period of time.

In pseudo code:

- Open subprocess
- write to it's stdout
- let program finish
- retrieve anything it spat out to stdout

I have tried the following:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(str(data))
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
result = p.communicate()[0]
```

However I get the following stack trace:

```
    result = p.communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in communicate .
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1396, in _communicate
    self.stdin.flush()
  ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `communicate`:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate(data)[0]
```

Comment: ah great, I won't pretend to know why, but that fixes the issue ;)